# When I press C-; in emacs+iterm2 why does it only get ;

Tags: keyboard, emacs, iterm2

I would like to use iedit-mode together with paredit-mode. When I bind C-; to iedit-mode globally, I still always get 'paredit-semicolon when I press C-;. I thought this was kind of weird. I recorded a keyboard macro to see if it would help me see which keys emacs was seeing and it only shows that I pressed ;, not C-;. Does this mean emacs isn't getting the C somehow? If so, why?

I am doing this with the latest homebrew emacs (24.2) in an iterm2 terminal window on a mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think terminals distinguish between `;` and `C-;`.  If you want to use `C-;`, I'm afraid you'll have to use the GUI version.  See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337837/send-c-to-emacs-in-vt100-xterm-terminal-mac-os-xs-terminal) about `C-(`.  You may be able to tell iTerm2 to send a hex code upon pressing `C-;` which you would then bind in emacs.  I haven't tried it though.